# Unexpectedly blank Ajax response text

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

I try to test my Ajax code with Node.js. I didn't use it before, so I'm newbie.
Here's my code:

```
<script>
  var xmlHttp = false;
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
    try {
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e2) {
        xmlHttp = false;
      }
    }
    @end @*/

  if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  function callServer() {
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/";
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
  }

  function updatePage() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
      var response = xmlHttp.responseText;
      alert(response);
    }
  }
</script>
```

And my Node.js server:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Test");
  response.end("Test");
}).listen(8888);
```

I run the script with  attribute: onclick="callServer()". And alert shows me nothing. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you ran node? Something like `node server` has to be sent using terminal or equivalent.

Comment: @KJPrice I'm sure. I added console.log at the end of the file and in the beginning of function(request, response).

Comment: I created a test server, and I saw `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`, did this appears on your console.log?

Comment: @fuyushimoya No. My edited code with console.log outputs this:
node test.js
Server has started
Request received(after button click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, the problem is that you are running your client on diffrent domain or port then your server runs.

Try to run your client on http://localhost:8888/.

**EDIT:**

It's very simple with Express package:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Test');
});

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(8888, function() {
  console.log('Server started at port 8888');
});
```

**EDIT#2**

Without Express:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs   = require('fs');    

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHeader(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(8888);

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
  if(req.url == '/test') {
    res.writeHeader(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('Test');
    res.end();
  }
});
```

**EDIT#3**

To serve static assets use [express.static](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#express.static) middleware like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You should place your assets to the `public` directory in the root.

Comment: How to run my client in localhost:8888? I didn't deploy my client anywhere. I mean, I got everything on my PC and I run .html files on it.

Comment: This code works, thank you so much. But is there a way without using Express?

Comment: Because I lost my js, css and fonts with express.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes:

1. Change

`xmlhttp.send(null);`
to  `xmlhttp.send();`

2. Change

`var xmlHttp = false;`  to  `var xmlHttp = null;`

3. Change if else to as below:

`if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari 
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} 
else { 
   // code for IE6, IE5 
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');}`

4. Below looks redundant, you may want to comment it:
   `// response.write("Test");`
5. Make sure node is running.

Best of luck.

Comment: Didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Try this change:  
from:    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});  
to:        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});